# How to only restore the weights of part layers of a model using Keras API in TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a deep model, and I want to initialize the weights of part layers of the model from another smaller trained subset model. How should I do?

In tensorflow 1.x, we can use `tf.train.Saver('List of weights variables')` and `tf.train.Saver.restore()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can read and write the weights as a list of NumPy arrays using `Layer.get_weights()` and `Layer.set_weights()`. `Model` inherits from `Layer`, so you can do this with a whole model or individual layers.

I would do file I/O using ordinary Python (are you using Python?) code such as some of the various NumPy file I/O functions https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.io.html. Maybe there's some methods for that in TensorFlow but I hope not.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any method that let `Layer.get_weights()` just load a part of layers?
I wrote a subclassed model, but I just want to load a part of layers of this model. When I use `Model.get_weights()`, it must load all the layers.

Comment: I found it works when I firstly got the model variables (list) by `Model.get_weights()`, and assigned my weights to a slice of the list variables, and then use `Model.set_weights()`. Thank you so much for your answer again.